# Same address for multiple symbols

Tags: linux, loader, symbols, nm, symbol-table

When reading symbol table from Linux kernel images, I found there are cases that one address is mapped to multiple symbols.

What does this mean? And how does loader work for this situation? Are they static functions, or something else?

```
c05eadb0 T _raw_write_unlock_bh
c05eadb0 T __lock_text_start
c05eadb0 T __sched_text_end
```